# What is the family of generating functions for the *rows* of this Stirling-number matrix for whose columns they are $\exp(\exp(x)-1)-1 $?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, generating-functions, stirling-numbers, infinite-matrices

*Remark: I give much background because it might significantly help to find an idea how to generate a solution*

I'm analyzing properties of a certain infinite matrix $U$, for whose columns we have the generating functions $$f_c(x) = (\exp(x)-1)^c \qquad \qquad c=-\infty...+\infty $$, assuming $c$ from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ (This is the type of Carleman-matrices extended to two-way-infinite size which Eri Jabotinsky has discussed in one article I've found in some archive...)
[image: matrixU]
Clearly the Stirling numbers 2nd kind are involved in the part of nonnegative column-indexes, but in the columns with negative index we have Zeta-values (or: Bernoulli-numbers) due to the generating functions having $\exp(x)-1$ to the negative power.

I succeded with finding that the generating functions ***for the rows*** are $$ g_r(x) = {1 \over 1+x}{1 \over \log(1+1/x)^{1+r}} \qquad \qquad c=-\infty...+\infty$$ for rowindex *r* from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ .
*(We can find the coefficients easier when we write $$ g^*_r(t)={t \over 1+t}{1 \over \log(1+t)^{1+r}} $$ get the Laurent-series for this and replace the powers of t by the negative powers of x .)*

---

Now, because I'm looking at iterations of the exponential function I've the matrix $U$ to the second power, $U^2$ which has the following entries around its zero-indexes:
[image: matrix]

Because the 2nd power of the matrix gives the second iterate of the function in the columns, I know that the generating functions of the columns are now $ f_{2,c}(x) = (\exp(\exp(x)-1)-1)^c$

***Q:*** My problem is now to find the generating functions of the rows. Simply writing the iterate of the rows-functions of the original version of $U$ seems to lead to nothing when I let Pari/GP do the expression. Does someone see how I could express them given the beginning of the sequence of coefficients? 
For instance, at row $r=0$ whe have $$g_{2,0}(x) = 1 -1/x + 4/3/x^2-15/8/x^3+122/45/x^4 + \cdots = ??? $$ or 
$$g^*_{2,0}(t) = 1 -1t + 4/3t^2-15/8t^3+122/45t^4 + \cdots = ??? $$
A meaningful suggestion for only one of the rows might already be helpful because the overall system should have a simple systematic derived from one key-idea as it is also for the non-iterated case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh, this looks very good...

By some trial & error I got the following scheme, which extends also nicely to higher powers of $U$ (or: iterates of $\exp(x)-1$). I got the following four families of generating functions for iteration-counts $h=0,1,2,3$ depending on rowindex $r$:
$$  \small \begin{array} {}
U^0:& g^*_{0,r}(t)&=& t \cdot{1 \over t^{1+r} }   \qquad  \qquad \text{note: $U^0$ is the identity-matrix}\\
U^1:& g^*_{1,r}(t)&=& t \cdot {1\over 1+t}\cdot{1 \over \log(1+t)^{1+r} }   \\
U^2:& g^*_{2,r}(t)&=&t \cdot {1\over 1+t}{1 \over 1+\log(1+t)}\cdot{1 \over \log(1+\log(1+t))^{1+r}}  \\
U^3:& g^*_{3,r}(t)&=& t \cdot {1\over 1+t}{1 \over 1+\log(1+t)}{1 \over 1+\log(1+\log(1+t))}\cdot {1 \over \log(1+\log(1+\log(1+t)))^{1+r}} \\
\end{array}
$$ and I assume that this is the general pattern also for the higher families.

Denoting $\Lambda(t)=\log(1+t)$ and for the iterations $\Lambda^{°h}(t)$ where $\Lambda^{°0}(t)=t$ we seem to have
$$ g^*_{h,r}(t) =  \left(\prod_{k=0}^{h-1} {1 \over 1+\Lambda^{°k}(t)} \right) \cdot {t \over \Lambda^{°h}(t)^{1+r}} $$

***Still open:*** an analytical justification/confirmation for this heuristic...
***Update 10. Jun 2015:*** [In this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/208900/7710) there is an analytical derivation valid for more general cases (functions of the type $f(x) = x + O(x^2)$ )