# Generalization for Stirling numbers 2nd kind to negative column-indexes?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, stirling-numbers, infinitesimals

The exponential generating functions for the Stirling numbers 2nd kind are the n'th powers of $f(x)=\exp(x)-1$ (where this is understood as formal power series, [Abramowitz&Stegun](http://dlmf.nist.gov/26.8), 26.8.12).

Generalizations of the Stirling numbers 2nd kind have sometimes been discussed ; if we take negative powers $n\lt 0$ we get powers of $ {1 \over \exp(x)-1 } $ as exponential generating functions the resulting coefficients are then compositions of bernoulli-numbers (even better: of zeta-values at negative arguments) ; but the logical recomputation for the Stirlingnumbers 2nd kind involve then formally divisions by $(-1)!$ and so that kind of generalizations from the left bottom area in the matrix below come out to be *infinitesimals*, and any manipulation with this should be complicated/nontrivial.

> ***Q:*** Does someone know, whether (and then where) this type of generalizations has been discussed?

---

The matrix below (truncated, should be of infinite size) shows the extension of the scaled Stirlingnumbers 2nd kind to negative column- and rowindices; the set of coefficients along the column *c* has the generating function $(\exp(x)-1)^c$.

[image: extended matrix of scaled Stirlingnumbers 2nd kind]

Here the unscaled coefficients; in the bottom right-section we see the Stirling numbers 2nd kind, in the bottom left area the "generalized" with negative column-index; the symbol "z" indicates the division by $(-1)!$ and we have thus infinitesimal expressions. Interestingly, in the top-left segment we find the Stirling numbers 1st kind (factorially rescaled).

[image: extended matrix of scaled Stirlingnumbers 2nd kind]

---

Note, this is a specific detail in the same area as in my earlier question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569751/what-is-the-family-of-generating-functions-for-the-rows-of-this-stirling-numbe?rq=1)

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9205211.pdf)? Formula 2.4 there might be of interest to you.

Comment: @j.m.:  Yes, I know it, thanks! It's long ago that I read it but with D. Knuth's articles it's always worth to read into them again...  Yes, the transposed relation is a common effect with many matrices - a simpler example is the Pascalmatrix which can similarly be extended (with its own inverse). In a closely related question in MO I ask for the relation between the "vertical" and "horizontal" generating functions (because I had a couple of interesting heuristiscs) and someone was able to show the systematic relation (I'll add the link when I have it)

Comment: So, doesn't that reflection relation answer the question in your title?

Comment: @j.m.: the generalization is a bit different; in my concept above the Stirling numbers first kind are cofactored with factorials while this is not so with Knuth's arrangement. And the article to which I linked in my own answer there is even another generalization - so I do not yet know the most opportune one. My main interest were in any case that numbers of the bottom-left quadrant (or say better : "formal symbols" because they only "enter reality" when the gamma(0) term is removed - which is somehow fiddling and needs much more consideration of why and when this is meaningful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fairly involved discussion in

> On Stirling numbers for complex arguments and Hankel contours
>    Philippe Flajolet, Helmut Prodinger
>    [Rapport de recherche, No 3373, Mar 1998](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/RR3373.ps)
>    INSTITUT NATIONAL DE RECHERCHE EN INFORMATIQUE ET EN AUTOMATIQUE
>    ISSN 0249-6399

They start with the same logic via the generating functions $(\exp(x)-1)^c$, they even generalize to complex indices in row and column. Unfortunately I can't follow that specific explanations by "Hankel-contour-integrals" yet.